# How to fix TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'resetButton.addEventListener')

Tags: javascript, button

```js
var colors = generateRandomColors(6);

var squares = document.querySelectorAll(".square");
var pickedColor = pickColor();
var colorDisplay = document.getElementById("colorDisplay");
var messageDisplay = document.querySelector("#message");
var h1 = document.querySelector("h1");
var resetButton = document.querySelector("#reset");

resetButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
 //generate all new colors
 colors = generateRandomColors(6);
 //pick a new random color from array
 pickedColor = pickColor();
 //change colorDisplay to match picked Color
 colorDisplay.textContent = pickedColor;
 //change colors of squares
 for(var i = 0; i < squares.length; i++) {
  squares[i].style.background = colors[i];
 }
 h1.style.background = "#232323";
});

colorDisplay.textContent = pickedColor;

for(var i = 0; i < squares.length; i++){
 // add initial colors to squares
 squares[i].style.background = colors[i];

 //add click listeners to squares
 squares[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
  //grab color of clicked squares
  var clickedColor = this.style.background;
  //compare color to pickedColor
  if(clickedColor === pickedColor) {
     messageDisplay.textContent = "Correct!";
     resetButton.textContent = "Play Again?";
     changeColors(clickedColor);
     h1.style.background = clickedColor;
  } else {
     this.style.background = "#232323";
     messageDisplay.textContent = "Try Again";
  }
 });
}

function changeColors(color) {
 //loop through all squares
 for(var i = 0; i < squares.length; i++) {
  //change each color to match given color
  squares[i].style.background = color;
 }
}

function pickColor() {
 var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length);
 return colors[random];
}

function generateRandomColors(num) {
 //make an array
 var arr = [];
 //add num random colors to arr
 for(var i = 0; i < num; i++) {
  //get random color and push into arr
  arr.push(randomColor());
 }
 //return that array
 return arr;
}

function randomColor() {
 //pick a "red" from 0 - 255
 var r = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
 //pick a "green" from 0 - 255
 var g = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
 //pick a "blue" from 0 - 255
 var b = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
 return "rgb(" + r + ", " + g + ", " + b + ")";
}
```

```css
body {
 background-color: #232323;
}

.square {
 width: 30%;
 background: purple;
 padding-bottom: 30%;
 float: left;
 margin: 1.66%;
}

#container {
 margin: 0px auto;
 max-width: 600px;
}

h1 {
 color: white;
}


#stripe {
 background: white;
 height: 30px;
 text-align: center;
 color: black;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Color Game</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="colorGame.css"> 
</head>
<body>
<h1>The Great <span id="colorDisplay">RGB</span> Color Game</h1>

<div id="stripe">
 <button id="reset">New Colors</button>
 <span id="message"></span>
</div>


 <div id="container">
  <div class="square"> </div>
  <div class="square"> </div>
  <div class="square"> </div>
  <div class="square"> </div>
  <div class="square"> </div>
  <div class="square"> </div>
 </div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="colorGame.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

I keep getting the "TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'resetButton.addEventListener')" error when I check the html console.

I was under the impression that we're all "copying code" from somewhere so I used Diffchecker to clean up my syntax but that wasn't enough. Modifying i < squares to  i < getSquare.length worked only when I moved the resetButton.add code to the bottom of my JS code

```
var colors = generateRandomColors(6);

var squares = document.querySelectorAll(".square");
var pickedColor = pickColor();
var colorDisplay = document.getElementById("colorDisplay");
var messageDisplay = document.querySelector("#message");
var h1 = document.querySelector("h1");
var resetButton = document.querySelector("#reset");

resetButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
    //generate all new colors
    colors = generateRandomColors(6);
    //pick a new random color from array
    pickedColor = pickColor();
    //change colorDisplay to match picked Color
    colorDisplay.textContent = pickedColor;
    //change colors of squares
    for(var i = 0; i < squares.length; i++) {
        squares[i].style.background = colors[i];
    }
    h1.style.background = "#232323";
});

colorDisplay.textContent = pickedColor;

for(var i = 0; i < squares.length; i++){
    // add initial colors to squares
    squares[i].style.background = colors[i];

    //add click listeners to squares
    squares[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
        //grab color of clicked squares
        var clickedColor = this.style.background;
        //compare color to pickedColor
        if(clickedColor === pickedColor) {
            messageDisplay.textContent = "Correct!";
            resetButton.textContent = "Play Again?";
            changeColors(clickedColor);
            h1.style.background = clickedColor;
        } else {
            this.style.background = "#232323";
            messageDisplay.textContent = "Try Again";
        }
    });
}

function changeColors(color) {
    //loop through all squares
    for(var i = 0; i < squares.length; i++) {
        //change each color to match given color
        squares[i].style.background = color;
    }
}

function pickColor() {
    var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length);
    return colors[random];
}

function generateRandomColors(num) {
    //make an array
    var arr = [];
    //add num random colors to arr
    for(var i = 0; i < num; i++) {
        //get random color and push into arr
        arr.push(randomColor());
    }
    //return that array
    return arr;
}

function randomColor() {
    //pick a "red" from 0 - 255
    var r = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
    //pick a "green" from 0 - 255
    var g = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
    //pick a "blue" from 0 - 255
    var b = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
    return "rgb(" + r + ", " + g + ", " + b + ")";
}
```

I got error notices elsewhere. All of my squares are purple.

Comment: We really don't want to see the code you are copying from. We want to see *all* of your relevant code. Please edit your question and include the HTML, CSS and JavaScript in a "code snippet" (button will be on the edit toolbar) so that we can reproduce your issue.

Comment: The errormessage probably means that at the time the Javascript runs, the DOM has no node with an id of `reset` so `document.querySelector("#reset")` returns `null`.

Comment: your code snippet seems to work perfectly here. it may be something wrong elsewhere